# onsubmit validation not working of 2 forms

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 forms in 1 div & I am using that hide & show & I have the same validation for both forms but issue is that onsubmit validation is not working in one form but in other form validation is working.

```js
function validateexpiry() {
    var today, someday;
    var exMonth=document.getElementById("exMonth").value;
    var exYear=document.getElementById("exYear").value;
    today = new Date();
    someday = new Date();
    someday.setFullYear(exYear, exMonth, 1);
    if (someday < today) {
        document.getElementById('invalidexpiry').innerHTML="Invalid expiry date";
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


function validate_cvv(cvv) {
    var myRe = /^[0-9]{3,4}$/;
    if(cvv.value.match(myRe)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('usernameError').innerHTML="Invalid CVV";
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="card" id="card" onsubmit="return validateexpiry(document.card.month,year)&& validate_cvv(document.card.cvv);">
  
  
  <form name="debitcard" id="debitcard" onsubmit="return validateexpiry(document.debitcard.month,year)&& validate_cvv(document.debitcard.cvv);">
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate both forms at the same time? Or are you saying that when you submit one form it works, but if you submit the other it doesn;t?

Comment: Provide your complete form code

Comment: card form validation is working but debitcard is not working

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: form is not submitting but no error. I am trying one only

Comment: Is the #debitcard form nested inside your #card form?

Comment: no form are not nested.  but both are in 1 div & i am using hide & show to display the form

Comment: kindly help me to get it correct

Comment: Hi form is not nested both are separate form in one div #Nicholas Robinson